# utf-8 handling by scribe (java) for facebook/twitter handling

Tags: java, utf-8, scribe

I am using scribe for oauth.  In the oauth response, I receive a list of names (some of which are non-english characters e.g.chinese/japanese).  Is scribe able to handle these characters (encode/decode in utf-8 compliant fashion) or is this responsibility of those implementing the api?  Has anyone come across the same issue and how did they resolve it (while using scribe).  Right now, if I print/log out the response.getBody, it displays characters which do not appear to be properly decoded.  It could possibly be an oversight on my end - I am simply seeking some useful suggestions.

My back end systems appear to be utf-8 compliant and able to handle utf-8 characters.

Comment: russian use encoding cp1251 in windows and koi-8 in unix, so utf-8 not necessary.

Comment: spaciba - may I ask if you handled russian characters using scribe (java api for social auth) and if so, did you add decoding on your own or relied on scribe for that?

Comment: I resent the fact that the Russian characters encode Unicode, although this is not necessary. Why Latin characters are not encoded in Unicode?

Comment: thanks for sharing.  I may have been wrong (scribe may be decoding the characters properly - I had an issue with another library) - I will update the post once I proceed further with my testing.

Comment: "appearing characters that is not properly decoded" actually decoded by the encoding to the destination that is expect another encoding to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used apache common lang for handling the messages & have not experienced an issue.  I would use prepared statements if this information would go to a relational DB.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Response [getStream](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/scribe/model/Response.java#L70-79) method and parse the contents with whatever encoding you want.

Comment: Thanks for responding - I will look into it if I run into any issues.